# What are the droids in this Clone Wars Legacy episode?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, the-clone-wars, droids

In the unfinished-but-still-canon Clone Wars Legacy, Bad Batch episode 3: "On the Wings of Keeradaks", the Techno Union facility was guarded by what seems to me as a new droid model. It has limbs that can unfold into four arms with built in blasters, and has winged flight capabilities.

What is this droid? What information do we know about it? Are there finished, fully rendered images of it? Does it exist in any of the finished Clone Wars episodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > What is this droid?

That is a [D-Wing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/D-wing_droid) droid.

2. > What information do we know about it?

> The D-wing droid was a type of battle droid used by the Techno Union—which was secretly allied with the Confederacy of Independent Systems—at their facility in the city of Purkell on Skako Minor. The D-wing droids were armed with built-in blasters and could use fold-out wings to enter flight mode, with an 
>   appearance and programming similar to the common Separatist B1 battle droid

3. > Are there finished, fully rendered images of it?

Unfortunately, no.

[image]

4. Does it exist in any of the finished Clone Wars episodes?

Nope, only the *Bad Batch* arc.